# Password handler return error even when password is matching

Tags: php

Here is the code for my password handler

```
    protected function passwordMatch($username, $password)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `profile` WHERE `username` = ?';
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$username]);
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        if (password_verify($result['password'], $password)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```
        if ($this->passwordMatch($this->username, $this->password) !== true) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Password not matching';
            header('Location: ../login.php');
            exit();
        }
```

Expecting: User would be logged on if username & password matches
Try: I tried changing from `!==` to `===` to see if that is going to fix the issue, but it would log the user in even if password not matching each other, otherwise I could not tell what is wrong with my code

If you want to see full code here: https://github.com/sammo-2000/login

Comment: `password_hash()` will always return different hashes, even for the same input so `$result['password'] === $password` will never be true. You need to use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against the hash you have in the DB.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that, I updated that part of code but still not working for some reason, check above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your github source code.

First of all, you have to extend your password length field in db.

```
ALTER TABLE `profile` 
MODIFY COLUMN `password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL AFTER `username`;
```

Then please use password_verify() function.

```
$sql = 'SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `profile` WHERE `username` = ?';
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$username]);
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    if(password_verify($password, $result["password"] )) {
        
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you are hashing the password in the `password_hash` before comparing?

Comment: The stored passwords are hashed as well, so I must hash them before comparing else it will not match